# kendo-ui grid, default templates and editors

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, durandal

I work in durandal project and enjoy using your kendo-ui-grid.

In my project, I need to build the grid-columns array dynamically.
i.e, I get (by ajax request) data-array of info about every grid-column and build the grid by loop over the data-array.

Here is my code:

```
   function initGrid(formInfo, FormFieldsInfo) {
        //=========================================
        //region: build dinamic fridColumns, gridSchema
        //=========================================
        var columns = [];
        var fields = {};
        var primaryKey = null;
        $.each(FormFieldsInfo, function addGridColumn(index, fieldInfo) {
            var column = {};
            column.field = fieldInfo.FieldName;
            column.headerTemplate = "<span class='headerGrid-att'>" + fieldInfo.DisplayTitle + "</span>";
            column.attributes = { "class": "columnBorder" };
            column.template = getColumnTemplate(fieldInfo.ComponentType, fieldInfo.FieldName);
            column.editor = getColumnEditor(fieldInfo.ComponentType);
            columns.add(column);

            var field = {};
            field.type = global.enums.fieldType[fieldInfo.FieldType];
            field.editable = true;
            fields[fieldInfo.FieldName] = field;

            if (fieldInfo.isKey == true) {
                primaryKey = fieldInfo.FieldName;
            }
        });

        vm.grid.gridOptions.columns = columns;

        vm.grid.schema = {
            data: 'Data',
            model: {
                id: primaryKey,
                fields: fields
            }
        };
        var dataQuery = {
            UserNo: global.cache.get(global.enums.cacheItems.USER).Id,
            ProcedureName: formInfo.SelectProcedure
        };
        //=========================================
        //end region: build dinamic fridColumns, gridSchema
        //=========================================

        vm.grid.dataSourceUrl = global.webApiConfig.getApiPath(global.enums.httpPath.GetETableGridData.path + '?query=' + JSON.stringify(dataQuery));
        vm.grid.remoteDataSource = true;           
        vm.grid.setDataSource();
        vm.grid.setGridOptionsSetting({ editable: "popup" });

    }

    function getColumnTemplate(type, fieldName) {
        switch (type) {
            case global.enums.componentType.checkBox:
                return function checkBoxTemplate(dataItem) {
                    return vm.grid.activeNotActiveTemplate(dataItem[fieldName])
                };
            case global.enums.componentType.dateTime:
                return function dateTemplate(dataItem) {
                    return vm.grid.ParseDateFormat(dataItem, fieldName)
                };
            default: //simple edit, combo
                return ???
        }
    }

    function getColumnEditor(type, fieldName) {
        switch (type) {

            case global.enums.componentType.date:
                return function dateEditor(container, options) {
                    vm.grid.datePickerEditor(container, options, false);
                }
            case global.enums.componentType.time:
                return function timeEditor(container, options) {
                    vm.grid.inputTimeEditor(container, options, new timeInput())
                }
            default: //simple edit,checkBox, combo
                return ???
        }
    }
```

My question is:

At regular grid, with consts columns array, I don't give any template or editor for regular fields (such as simple string data), and don't give any editor to boolean-checkBox column.

But, in this case, I must return template/editor function always.
So, what can I do?
What is the defult code that I have to write? (What do I have to write insead of the ??? marks?)

Thank you!

Comment: What if you generate an HTML `<table>` from your dynamic columns, then   use `$('#newTableId').kendoGrid({...})` on that generated table to create the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `???` by `undefined`, this will make it call default method.